# generate rownum in select statement without using db specific functions

Tags: sql

I want to get the rownumbers in sql select statement but it shouldn't be DB specific query like I cant use rownum of oracle.Please let me know how can i achieve this.
I have table structure as follows pid,emplid,desc as colums and pid and emplid combination will be used as primary key. So suggest the query in this use case.

Thanks,
Shyam

Comment: return your result as an array then `count($result)` but why do you need like that it's weird way to do this.

Comment: `row_number()` is standard ANSI SQL so that *is* the DBMS independent way.

Comment: I have table structure as follows  pid,emplid,desc as colums and pid and emplid combination will be used as primary key. So suggest the query in this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it you table has to have an unique `Id`- like field - anything to distinguish one row from another.  If it is then:

```
select t1.*,
(select count(id) from t as t2 where t2.id<=t1.id) as row_number

from t as t1 order by Id
```

UPD: if you have 2 columns to make an order then it will look like:

```
select t1.*,
(select count(id) from t as t2 where t2.id1<=t1.id1 and t2.id2<=t1.id2) 
as row_number

from t as t1 order by Id1,id2
```

Comment: I have 2 columns which will be part of key so how can i redefine above query.

Comment: @user2392923 I've added a query for 2 columns

Answer (score 1):

The `row_number()` function is supported on a lot of the major RDBMS but I don't believe it's in MySQL so it really depends how agnostic you want it to be. Might be best to move it out of the database layer if you want it truly agnostic.

EDIT:  valex's method of calculating rownum is probably a better option than moving it out of DB

Comment: valex' solution will be *much* slower than using the standard `row_number()`.